# R script in php

Tags: php, r

I am running the php script containing Rscript in terminal. its working fine and giving the output. but the same script if i call from the webpage its not giving any output. i have checked the folder permission also. please help me to fix this.

my php script:

```
<?php
$abc=exec('Rscript dist/GS_R2html.R');
print "$abc\n";
?>
```

Rscript:

```
a<-rnorm(1000)
library(R2HTML)
setwd('/var/www/test')
HTML.title("Data Summary", file="dist/gshtml.htm",append=F)
HTML(summary(a),file="dist/gshtml.htm",align="left")
HTML(matrix(a[1:100],nrow=10,byrow=T),file="dist/gshtml.htm",align="left")
HTML.title("Histogram", file="dist/gshtml.htm") 
jpeg("dist/plot2.jpg")
hist(a,col="red")
HTMLInsertGraph("dist/plot2.jpg",file="dist/gshtml.htm",Align="left")   
dev.off()
```

Comment: try the full path to Rscript in your call

Comment: i tried giving full path too

Comment: Have you tried the php script in the terminal of the same computer where you host the webpage? Have you tried to call a more simplified R script, just to see if the php -> R connection works?

Comment: try `$abc=exec('Rscript 2>&1');` see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-bash-shell-what-is-21

Answer (score 0):

Its due to the missing of the rApache which supports web application development using the R  and the Apache web server. I followed the steps mentioned in the http://rapache.net/manual.html to install and configure R in Apache.